# Internal Server Error while run my website

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have uploaded my website on cpanel. When I open it I see

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@testme.com to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

What can I do for this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a 404 page first of all -> that is the final part of your error.

The misconfiguration '500 inernal server error' is nearly always caused by an incorrect .htaccess file - check that you have the correct `RewriteBase` defined.

Comment: my htaccess file is in the mode of 0644

Comment: no - the actual contents of your .htaccess file is probably wrong. 0644 is fine for .htaccess - 0644 is just defining read, write execute properties - it has nothing to do with the contents of it - open the file and see what `RewriteBase` says

Answer (score 1):

Try to see the server log error. The details where the error occurred are stored and there are a wide variety of reasons for internal server error. Apache2 server logs can be seen at:

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

You can also see the access.log at `/var/log/apache2/access.log`

Besides, you can see the [cPanel error logs](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/ErrorLog)

I also faced a similar internal server error on my drupal 6 website and error log showed me that I called an undefined json function(not installed on server then).